# How to enlarge java swing panel

Tags: java, swing

I create some panel with a lot of components as images text ... . Now I have one problem. Customers tell me that panel is too small. Is there some option to enlarge this whole panel or I have to enlarged components one by one ?

UPDATE:

from this: [image]

to this: [image]

Comment: By enlarge do you mean maximize it to the screen size?

Comment: nope this panel is already maximazed. But lets say I have 2 label with this panel with font size 12 now I want to enlarge this components to size 20...

Comment: Have you suggested to the user - a smaller screen-resolution or adjusting the Appearance and Personalization|Display  settings (Windows 7, but other OS would have something similar)?  Java creates fonts that are 'about the same size' as the rest of the fonts used on the system.  I find it hard to believe your clients can read those fonts, but not the ones from Java!

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: Assuming correct use of `LayoutManager` and default font sizes, on Mac OS X, use `System Preferences > Universal Access > Zoom`.

Comment: I just add images. in first images I set border to aaaaaa so you can see panel which I want to enlarge

Comment: It would also be helpful if you post the code for the panel. Then we can see exactly how you do the layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

everything depends of used `LayoutManager`,

```
Is there some option to enlarge this whole panel or I have to enlarged 
components one by one
```

-> no, basically this is reason why `LayoutManager` exists there, most of them there are created especially for this reasons, `GridLayout`, `GridBagLayout`, `BoxLayout` (maybe without `glue`), `BorderLayout` and todays `MigLayout` are best way how to do it

Answer (score 0):

it depends, if you have a GridLayout or some Layout witch set all the components with some order, for example, all the components at the same distance or all the components like a Matrix, if you enlarge the panel, all the components will enlarge with it. If not, you have to enlarge by hand.